# Vagrant saving current state when windows reboots

Tags: git, lamp, vagrant

I am running vagrant with ubuntu as guest os, but when windows reboots, i again have to install LAMP and configure virtual hosts and also all apps like git, memcache again.

How can i save the state of the VM using vagrant when the windows shuts down?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't provided a lot of information in your question. Also, what research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: i used Oracle VM VirtualBox manager GUI to save the state, but when windows reboots, still not able to get vagrant reload and also no virtual machines listed on VM manager :(

Comment: Need more information... Are there any duplicate Vagrant VMs in the VirtualBox interface after reboot? Are you shutting down your Windows host or is it sleeping? Do you run any Vagrant commands before sleep / shutdown? When logging in to Windows again (after a sleep or shutdown), what Vagrant command you you run to bring the VM back up? Are you using any provisioners or plugins in Vagrant? Can you paste your Vagrantfile? This would all be great information to add to your original question.

Answer (score 5):

I know I'm a little late to the party here, but I recently ran into this myself when I was learning to use Vagrant, and the docs don't make it completely obvious.  I was shutting down the VM with `vagrant halt` and then using `vagrant up` the next time I turned on my PC, and this would destroy the VM state and make you start over.

**In order to keep the same VM around and not loose its state, use the `vagrant suspend` and `vagrant resume` commands.**    This will make your VM survive a host machine reboot with its state intact.

Of course, the entire idea behind Vagrant is that the process of provisioning the VM should bring it completely up to a usable state with no extra setup required.  You should look into integrating some Chef cookbooks with your VM, or at least writing up some shell scripts to install and configure your LAMP stack.